# How to read a certain column from a csv file?

Tags: c#, csv

I am currently programming a finance app for stocks,
My program downloads the CSV file of the selected stock,
But now I want to get values from only ONE column,
How do I do that?
And how do I get all the values into a list so that I can use them in LiveChart:

```
Values = new ChartValues<double> { VALUELISTHERE },
```

I've looked at a lot of posts and couldn't get anything to work. (getting values from only one column.)

Comment: Do you know how to read all the columns? If so, do that, and then run the output of that through a LINQ statement that `Select`s only the column you are interested in

Comment: CSV files are plain text, so directly _getting values from only one column_ without reading the whole file is obviously impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [CSVHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) library. But I don't think you will be able to read only one column from all the rows but here is [an example](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/reading/enumerate-class-records) from library's page which can help:

```
void Main()
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader("path\\to\\file.csv"))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        var record = new Stock();
        var list=new List<double>();
        var records = csv.EnumerateRecords(record);
        foreach (var r in records)
        {
            // r is the same instance as record.
            //ADD VALUES FOR REQUIRED COLUMN TO THE LIST
            list.Add(r.ChartValue);
        }
    }
}

public class Stock
{
    public double ChartValue { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: thanks, i got it to work, yesterday! but do you know how i can get a double number in this format: 0.00 or if greater 000.00 / 0.000.000 ?

Comment: any example rows from the file? if it is in that format (`00.000`) it should be able to read it with that precession.